# After Drake Source installation on macOS, how to run a example?

Tags: drake

After using "Source installation on macOS" to install drake, "Bazel built//..."  and " Bazel test//..." are done. The question is: how I run an example , for examples/acrobot/run_swing_up ? Should I input a command like: Bazel-bin/examples/acrobot/run_swing_up ?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you can either run it via `bazel run` or `./bazel-bin` (the latter being better for running multiple processes, having stdin access, etc.):

https://drake.mit.edu/bazel.html

Some of the examples also have brief READMEs or docs on how to run it; e.g.:

- [jaco arm](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/1ee145e9c322485bb8c16114256d63817d8ba2b9/examples/kinova_jaco_arm)
- [inclined plane](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/1ee145e9c322485bb8c16114256d63817d8ba2b9/examples/multibody/inclined_plane_with_body)